# Query Files in a USB OTG using MediaStore fails

Tags: android, file, usb, mediastore, usb-otg

```
val projection = arrayOf( MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME )
val selection  = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.RELATIVE_PATH + " = '/'"

val mediaStoreVolumes = MediaStore.getExternalVolumeNames(requireActivity())
mediaStoreVolumes.forEach { volume ->
    val uri    = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(volume)
    val cursor = cr.query(uri, projection, selection, null, null)
    if (cursor != null) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Log.e("Volume: "+volume, "File: "+ cursor.getString(0))
        }
        cursor.close()
    }
}
```

The above code print file names in 'external_primary' and SDCARD. But for USB OTG it fails with exception:

```
 E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.starsolutions.starfilemanager, PID: 10093
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Volume a80d-7c6d not found
```

But the volume name is returned by MediaStore by `MediaStore.getExternalVolumeNames()`

**Is it possible to list files in a USB OTG drive using MediaStore API?**

Comment: Which statement exactly causes the exception?

Comment: val cursor = cr.query(uri, projection, selection, null, null). If the Uri is for external_primary or sdcard, there is no issue.

Comment: Did some tests and indeed we get an IllegalArgumentException querying the usb stick. Further i do not know if it should be possible. Before you can do a query() the MediaStore should first have scanned/indexed the usb stick... WIth SAF there are no problems.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files Quote: The MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission grants the following:  ....`Access to the root directory of both the USB on-the-go (OTG) drive and the SD card.` But to no avail. Or i do not know what special to do for a stick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug of Android 11. It fixed in android 12.
https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/246857526

Comment: I have tried this with Android 12 and 14 but I can only list the volume name of the USB OTG. I can't seem to get any files using MediaStore. I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Volume VOLUME_NAME not found` even after enabling `ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION`. I was only able to access data on the usb otg using the Storage Access Framework to open a document tree intent